# C++ How to print most typed word in a map

Tags: c++

Currently it prints how many times each word was printed. But how can I make it to print the most repeated word?

> Input: 5
>
> apple, banana, apple, apple, banana
>
> Output:
>
> 3 apple
>
> 2 banana

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, int> freq;
    string word;
    int max;
    while (cin >> word)
    {
        freq[word]++;
    }

    map<string, int>::const_iterator iter;
    for (iter = freq.begin(); iter != freq.end(); ++iter) {
        cout << iter->second << " " << iter->first << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Although I thought this was answered sufficiently in your previous question where the answer showed you how to sort based on frequency, A beginner way (without the sort or the lambda) is find the maximum of `iter->second` in a loop.

Comment: A simple way to do this, without taking advantage of some of the std methods, would be to check inside the `for` for the biggest value. `for(iter = freq.begin(), word = iter->first, max = iter->second; ...){` and then inside you could just check if `iter->second` is bigger than the `max` variable, you just update `word` and `max` with the new `iter` values.

Comment: you mean `if(iter->second > max) max = iter->second;`

Comment: You can even make a second iterator variable and update it to the current item each time the max changes. That way you would not have to search for the max item after the max was found to get the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) and a functor that compares the pair's from the map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    using mmap = map<string, int>;
    mmap freq;

    std::string data = "apple banana apple banana apple";
    std::istringstream iss(data);

    string word;
    while (iss >> word)
        freq[word]++;

    auto iter = std::max_element(std::begin(freq), std::end(freq), [] 
                (const mmap::value_type& a, const mmap::value_type& b) 
                { return a.second < b.second; });

    std::cout << iter->first << " " << iter->second;
}
```

Output:

`apple 3`

Comment: Im trying to change your code a bit to add a `cin`, but I cannot end the while loop to end the program with ctrl+z enter

Comment: @Jemi You can use your same input code without much change. I mean get rid of `iss` and `data` and use `std::cin` the same way you did in your code the rest is the same.

Comment: I did it myself. Thank you very much.